# Improving Low Contrast Image Segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, contrast

I have phase-contrast microscopy images that needs to be segmented. It seems very difficult to segment them due to the lack of contrast between the objects from the background (image 1). I used the function `adapthisteq` to increase the visibility of the cells (image 2). Is there any way I can improve the segmentation of the cells?

```
normalImage = imread(fileName);
channlImage = rgb2gray(normalImage);
histogramEq = adapthisteq(channlImage,'NumTiles',[50 50],'ClipLimit',0.1);
saturateInt = imadjust(histogramEq);
binaryImage = im2bw(saturateInt,graythresh(saturateInt));
binaryImage = 1 - binaryImage;
```

normalImage - raw image
[image: normalImage]
histogramEq - increased visibility image
[image: histogramEq]
binaryImage - binarized image
[image: binaryImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to apply the threshold, I would separate the different patterns from the background by using a white top-hat. See [here the result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/62wCt-WhiteTopHat.png). Then you [stretch the histogram](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/stretch.htm).

Then you can apply what you did.

Comment: Hi, I added the line `tophatImage = imtophat(histogramEq,strel('disk',7))` after `histogramEq`. The result looks very similar to yours but the difference is that the objects of interest seems brighter compared to the background in yours. How did you brighten the objects of interest? What do you mean by `stretching the histogram`?

Comment: My advise was to apply the top hat before the adapthisteq, not after. The top-hat is not sensitive to illumination variations. I've added a link about the histogram stretching.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to help with accurate segmentation.

Comment: Can you share your image after top-hat+ histogramEq?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to build up on FiReTiTi's answer. I have the code below and some screenshots. I have done this using OpenCV 3.0.0

```
import cv2

x = 'test.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(x, 1)
cv2.imshow("img",img)

#----converting the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
```

[image]

```
#----binarization of image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
```

[image]

```
#----performing adaptive thresholding
athresh=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(thresh, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
cv2.imshow('athresh', athresh)
```

[image]

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(7, 7))

#----morphological operation
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(athresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('closing', closing)
```

[image]

```
#----masking the obtained result on the grayscale image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask= closing)
cv2.imshow('result ', result )
```

[image]